# Selenium clicking button hidden by span

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate an environment selection screen where there are multiple selectable buttons individually hidden by a span, these display as tiles.

I have managed to navigate to a given tile and pull up the button but I am unable to click it.

Here is the code I have

```
    public static void NavigateToEnvironment(IWebDriver driver, string environment)
    {
        IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.00));

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath($"//span[text()='{environment}']")));
        var tile = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//span[text()='{environment}']"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.MoveToElement(tile).Perform();

        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath($"//*[@span=(text()='{environment}')][@btn=(starts-with(text(), 'Start'))]")));

        driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[starts-with(text(), 'Start')]")).Click();

    }
```

The first part successfully moves to the correct tile and opens the span so on screen the button is there. 
The wait.until condition is fine too so Selenium can see the element so its the final click command I have an issue with.

It seems only to look for the button hidden within tile one but I am trying tile three. All the buttons have the same HTML tags.

In the current code state I get element not visible.

I have tried to use the xpath as in the wait condition but that returns that the parameters are not elements so again fails.

I am kind of at a loss. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Some HTML of one of the buttons. This basically repeats with a different application name

```
<li class="trans tile">
                <div class="tileWrap noselect" aria-haspopup="true">
                    <div class="divNavIcon">
                        <span class="spnNavIcon primarycolorfont enable" data-bind="css: Code"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tilePopup primarycolor">
                        <span data-bind="text: ApplicationNameAlias ? ApplicationNameAlias : ApplicationName">Enable QA</span>
                        <span data-bind="text: Description" class="tileSubText">Enable CI Environment</span>
                        <div class="tilePopupToggle">
                            <button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.startApp, css: { disabled: IsRevoked }" class="btn">Start <i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" style="display:none;" data-bind="click: $parent.startAppNew, css: { disabled: IsRevoked }" class="btn">Start New <i class="fa fa-fw fa-external-link"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" style="display:none;" data-bind="attr: { &quot;data-target&quot;: &quot;#appPreview_&quot; + ApplicationID }" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#appPreview_3043">Preview <i class="fa fa-fw fa-play"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Screenshot to help understanding - Each tile acts in the same way with a hidden start button. My code works fine for this first tile but if I want the second or third tiles it cannot find the start button

[image: Screenshot to help understanding]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question to a specific requirement as which element you exactly want to click `Start`,`Start New` or `Preview`

Comment: To be honest i'm not all that up to speed with HTML so can't tell you why there is 3 buttons there. As I see on the screen it is the 'Start' that I am after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed a pretty elegant work around to this issue. The buttons are contained in li items so i'm just finding the relevant one of those.

```
public void NavigateToEnvironment(IWebDriver driver, string environment)
        {
            var tile = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//span[text()='{environment}']"),5);

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(tile).Perform();

            var tile2 = driver
                    .FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/ul"))
                    .FindElements(By.TagName("li"))
                    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Text))
                    .ToList();

            var singleTile = tile2.Single(x => x.Text.Contains(environment));
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/ul/li[{tile2.IndexOf(singleTile) + 1}]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button[1]")).Click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the button with text as **Start** you can use the following code block :

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='tilePopup primarycolor']//div[@class='tilePopupToggle']/button[@class='btn' and normalize-space()='Start']/i[@class='fa fa-fw fa-desktop']"))).Click();
```

---

### Update

Can you try removing the `<button>` tag as :

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='tilePopup primarycolor']//div[@class='tilePopupToggle']//i[@class='fa fa-fw fa-desktop']"))).Click();
```

> **Note** : As per [aurelia/binding/issues/163](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/163) **disable.bind disables button but inner content is still clickable** and we are targeting `i[@class='fa fa-fw fa-desktop']`

Comment: This is still suffering with the problem I was having. It works perfectly if it is looking for the button behind the first tile but cant find it under any of the other tiles. I think its needs to have this span line specified by the different application names `<span data-bind="text: ApplicationNameAlias ? ApplicationNameAlias : ApplicationName">Enable QA</span>`

Comment: I am unable to understand `button behind the first tile` but are you seeing any errors? Update the question with the error stack trace please.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show you what I mean. I'm not getting any errors from your code example as its just timing out

Comment: Check out my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Unfortunately same issue. I really appreciate your help to this point