# Get HTML list position from Xpath based on other criteria

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

As a follow on to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948760/selenium-clicking-button-hidden-by-span)  which has not yet got a workable answer I have been investigating a work around but go stuck again.

Basically I am wondering if you are able to get the list position from HTML based on some search criteria?

This will allow me to recreate the actual xpath of the button which looks like this `//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button[1]`

I've tried a few variations but it always return null.

Here is my latest trial

```
var item 
=  driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//span[text()='{environment}']/ancestor::li"));
            var id = item.GetAttribute("li").IndexOf("li");
```

And the HTML looks like this - 
[image]

The highlighted line is the search term `'{environment}'` (Enable QA in this example) And the button I am trying to click is below.

Comment: Do you want to get only the <li> from the given HTML image?

Comment: I think so yes. For the environment search I used in the example I expect it to return 3 as it is the third <li> tag

Comment: you have to store all the list items in List then have to iterate with for loop to get the index "environment". And in your code you used item.GetAttribute("li") which is the wrong li is not attribute here it's an tag name.

Comment: Ok that sounds reasonable. How would I go about doing that? I relatively new to this kind of coding so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as example:

```
List<WebElement> th = table.FindElements(By.tagName("li"));
int listsize = th.size();
for(int i=0;i<listsize;i++)
{
    String listtext = th.get(i).getText();
    if(listtext.equals("Environment"))
    {
       return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I think we are getting somewhere but I am now stuck on this line of your solution `String listtext = th.get(i).getText();` it doesnt like the get, I only have GetType, GetHashCode or GetEnumerator. Any ideas?

Comment: Above code is in java sorry for the confution in C# :   String listtext=  th[i].Text;

Comment: Took a little bit of tweaking but it now works perfectly! 3 days of trying and you fixed it in about 20 minutes! Thanks